# Congiuntivo "fossi" o condizionale "sarei" nella seguente frase

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

> Ho rinunciato, pensando che quando *fossi*/*sarei* arrivato qui l'avrei preso.

Nella frase sopra si usa "fossi" o "sarei"? O vanno bene entrambe a seconda delle situazioni?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il tuo è un bellissimo esempio della difficoltà di interpretazione delle regole italiane sull'uso di congiuntivo e condizionale.

Tu vuoi dire:

> «Ho rinunciato, pensando che poi sarei arrivato qui e l'avrei preso»

cioè:

> «Ho rinunciato, pensando che l'avrei preso dopo esser arrivato qui».

Cioè quel "quando" introdurrebbe una subordinata temporale, non un'ipotetica: era certo fin dal principio che tu saresti arrivato lì dove adesso sei. E la temporale è quasi contemporanea rispetto all'azione successiva.

Secondo me, il condizionale ci potrebbe pure stare *benché questo potrebbe* (o possa?) essere considerato "substandard" da molti linguisti che forse preferirebbero l'uso del congiuntivo:

> «Ho rinunciato, pensando che, quando fossi arrivato qui, l'avrei preso»

dove però la temporale si confonde con l'ipotetica e qualsiasi diversa sfumatura si vanifica.

Considera anche che [Giorgio De Rienzo](http://www.corriere.it/Rubriche/Scioglilingua/2003/31ottobre.shtml), linguista del Corriere della Sera, considera accettabile la frase, simile alla tua:

> «Le ho detto che avresti richiamato non appena ti saresti liberata»

e anche [qui](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=1432) si dà per buona la frase:

> «Avrei aspettato fino a quando sarebbe arrivato»

Come osserva nico nel commento, si tratta di un'applicazione della regola del [futuro nel passato](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/futuro-nel-passato_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/).

In questo e altri casi simili, la scelta sta a te: usare il condizionale e correre il rischio di incappare in qualche caso perverso da far storcere il naso all'interlocutore, oppure usare il congiuntivo e andare sul sicuro? Se scegli la prima strada e ci azzecchi potresti uscirtene fuori in maniera brillante; altrimenti ci fai una figuraccia!

---

Noto che ne hanno parlato [qui](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=4365) pochi giorni fa, con altri esempi:

> «I suoi resti sarebbero rimasti abbandonati al suolo fino a che le streghe non li avrebbero raccolti»
>
> «Quando avrebbe lasciato la sua casa per trasferirsi, allo stadio avrebbero dovuto dedicarle uno striscione»

(la prima è OK; la seconda potrebbe essere corretta o far impallidire, a seconda del contesto …).

Comment: Vedi anche: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/futuro-nel-passato_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/

Comment: @nico Manzoni mi era venuto in mente anche senza leggere la pagina che hai indicato. `;-)`

Answer (score -3):

Ho chiesto di poterla leggere quando te ne fossi/saresti andato.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su ItalianSE! Potresti aggiungere qualche particolare alla tua risposta?